# Python matplotlib subplot datetime x ticks cutomization

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, subplot

A solution to customize the x-axis dates is readily available at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html. I want to customize it further. The solution is

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

base = datetime.datetime(2005, 2, 1)
dates = np.array([base + datetime.timedelta(hours=(2 * i))
                  for i in range(732)])
N = len(dates)
np.random.seed(19680801)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(N))
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, constrained_layout=True, figsize=(6, 6))

for nn, ax in enumerate(axs):
    locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
    formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
    formatter.formats = ['%y',  # ticks are mostly years
                         '%b',       # ticks are mostly months
                         '%d',       # ticks are mostly days
                         '%H:%M',    # hrs
                         '%H:%M',    # min
                         '%S.%f', ]  # secs
    # these are mostly just the level above...
    formatter.zero_formats = [''] + formatter.formats[:-1]
    # ...except for ticks that are mostly hours, then it is nice to have
    # month-day:
    formatter.zero_formats[3] = '%d-%b'

    formatter.offset_formats = ['',
                                '%Y',
                                '%b %Y',
                                '%d %b %Y',
                                '%d %b %Y',
                                '%d %b %Y %H:%M', ]
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

    ax.plot(dates, y)
    ax.set_xlim(lims[nn])
axs[0].set_title('Concise Date Formatter')

plt.show()
```

Present output:

[image]

The above code adds the year of the data at end of the x-axis. I want to add the year of the data at start of the a-axis as well. In the first subplot x-axis, 2015 appears at end of the x-axis. How do I make it appear at start of the x-axis as well?

Comment: You cannot do so easily; the extra date information is in the "offset" for the axes, and that is in a fixed location on the axes, I believe.  However, you could get the text of the first tick, and add a carriage return to the text and add the year.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Having not familiar with the subplots, I have not fully understood. But you seem to know whats hapenning there. Can you help me about how should I approach it?

Comment: @JodyKlymak I appreciate your inputs on my new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64225835/python-subplot-matplotlib-depriciatiion-warning-in-colorbar-plots

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is using `text` to add the texts, but it is not automatic, need some adjustments. Or you can get the tightbbox of axe, and add text according to the bbox. Here I put the most simple way: adding text relative to axes.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

dates = np.array([base + datetime.timedelta(hours=(2 * i))
                  for i in range(732)])
N = len(dates)
np.random.seed(19680801)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(N))

lims = [(np.datetime64('2005-02'), np.datetime64('2005-04')),
        (np.datetime64('2005-02-03'), np.datetime64('2005-02-15')),
        (np.datetime64('2005-02-03 11:00'), np.datetime64('2005-02-04 13:20'))]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, constrained_layout=True, figsize=(6, 6))

for nn, ax in enumerate(axs):
    locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
    formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
    formatter.formats = ['%y',  # ticks are mostly years
                         '%b',       # ticks are mostly months
                         '%d',       # ticks are mostly days
                         '%H:%M',    # hrs
                         '%H:%M',    # min
                         '%S.%f', ]  # secs
    # these are mostly just the level above...
    formatter.zero_formats = [''] + formatter.formats[:-1]
    # ...except for ticks that are mostly hours, then it is nice to have
    # month-day:
    formatter.zero_formats[3] = '%d-%b'

    formatter.offset_formats = ['',
                                '%Y',
                                '%b %Y',
                                '%d %b %Y',
                                '%d %b %Y',
                                '%d %b %Y %H:%M', ]
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

    ax.plot(dates, y)
    ax.set_xlim(lims[nn])
axs[0].set_title('Concise Date Formatter')
axs[0].text(0, -0.28, 'Feb 2005', transform=axs[0].transAxes)
axs[1].text(0, -0.28, 'Feb 2005', transform=axs[1].transAxes)
axs[2].text(0, -0.28, '04 Feb 2005', transform=axs[2].transAxes)
```

[image]