# Python subplot matplotlib depriciatiion warning in colorbar plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have coded to produce colorbar plots. The code is working perfectly. Now I have created a for loop to draw 4 such plots. The code runs and produces one plot and exists a depreciation warning. I could not decode what is wrong here and why did not produce all 4 plots.

```
samdf = pd.DataFrame({'x':random.sample(range(-100,100),20),
                    'y':random.sample(range(-200,400),20),
                    'z':random.sample(range(-1500,1500), 20),
                    'k':random.sample(range(-2500,500), 20),
                    'l':random.sample(range(-100,3500), 20)})
cmaplist = ['y','z','k','l']
for i in cmaplist: 
    plt.scatter(samdf.index,samdf['x'],
                                c=samdf[i], cmap='jet',
                label=i,vmin=samdf[i].min(), vmax=samdf[i].max())
    fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.95)
    cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.90, 0.15, 0.02, 0.83]) ### (colorbar xposition,yposition,width, height)
    cbar=plt.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)
    cbar.set_label('%s '%(i))#'POA irrad. (W/m$^2$)')
    # Set common labels
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.06, right=0.89, top=0.99, bottom=0.15)        
    plt.show()
```

Present output:

[image]

```
    <ipython-input-11-a3b6e265d62a>:20: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous 
axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, 
this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
      cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.90, 0.15, 0.02, 0.83]) ### (colorbar xposition,yposition,width, height)
    <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

Comment: @Jody Klymak can you help here.

Comment: I can only assume you are making the colorbar twice somehow.  But without a minimal working example it is not possible to tell.  Have you tried `constrained_layout` rather than placing the colorbar manually and playing with subplots_adjust?

Comment: You are encouraged to put complete code here, not just part of your code.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I have modified my question with a reproducible example.

Comment: @ted930511 I have modified my question with a reproducible example.

Comment: `im` isn't defined above, nor are the imports.  However, it looks like your problem is you continually call `cbar_ax = fig.add_axes` inside the loop.  So you are overwriting the same axes each time.

Comment: @JodyKlymak So, how do I address this? Shifting this outside will not produce all the plots right?

Comment: Why not? Like I don't know because I have no idea what `im` is.  Do you want 4 colorbars for some reason?

Comment: @JodyKlymak The code meant to produce four plots and hence four colorbars. So, i need to have it under for loop right? not outside of it.

Comment: Then you shouldn’t place all the colorbars manually in the same spot.  Why are you placing them manually instead of just letting matplotlib place them beside the axes?

Comment: @JodyKlymak I did not know how to let the code place it. I tried. It placed the colorbar on the top of the subplots. So, then I decided to place it manually. How do I let my code place it automatically without interfering with the actual plot?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html#colorbars

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks to the reference document. I did refer that and used the following in my code `cbar=fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, shrink=0.2)
    cbar.set_label('Bar title')`. It gave me the following error `
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'right'`

Comment: Your example is still irreproducible, so very hard to say what the problem is, or to know exactly what you tried.